Why is my Node.js HTTP2 Server unable to properly serve both Static Files and JavaScript?
So I'm currently trying to make a simple page that will send a request with a button. I'm struggling with getting the server to host the index.html without any issue at all. I have two issues which occur.
If I use slightly working server code, the console will log a problem with the request sending code in the client. Any other server code doesn't work and gives me undefined errors.
I found out that when I use the live server VSCode extension, it works properly in generating the request but I cant actually have the request send to the server since the server code isn't actually running due to the extension. If I try to use my own server with node server.js, the code will only work with a very specific server code that I wrote earlier that doesn't work properly and gives me some errors.
Here is the index.html code thats responsible for calling the Javascript to send the request:
<button id="sendOfferButton">Send Offer</button>
<p id="status">Status: Waiting for interaction...</p>
<script src="script.js"></script>

Below is the server.js code which will allow the html to work, but gives me an issue where the script.js doesn't work and gives me this console error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

which I tested and found out is related to this line:
<script src=script.js></script> 

Meaning it doesn't seem to be able to access the request generation code.
This is what I have in server.js:
const http2 = require('http2');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'server.key')),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'server.cert'))
};
const server = http2.createSecureServer(options, (req, res) => {
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../client', 'index.html');

    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.statusCode = 500;
            res.end('Internal Server Error');
            return;
        }

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.end(data);
    });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server running on https://localhost:3000');
});

I have a pretty limited understanding of the http2 process and how it works so I don't understand why the code I've tried won't allow it to function properly. My best guess is the way I'm currently trying to implement the server is using strictly a static approach and cant do any updates with the script.js after its been loaded?
I'm not particularly sure how to make sure my server can function properly. I already verified that the client works properly and now my problem is just with just figuring out how to correctly get the server to host.

script.js looks like server code, you shouldn't load it into the browser.

But that doesn't explain the error. The error message says that there's an unexpected < character in server.js, which would happen if you have HTML in the file.

What do the browser tools tell you?  Total guess is a 404 error page but you should be able to tell from what the server sends back.

JS is executed on client side, simply server your file.js and let the browser do the work

You seem very confused about your code. I'm guessing that you opened the html file directly and expected it to send request to the server?

Not exactly sure what you mean, but yes after running the server code, I expected index.html to be able to properly run the script when the script.js was run.
Browser tools tell me that the index.html and server code do work, but the when the button is pressed, nothing happens. As in the button doesnt send the request or log anything.

open up developer tools network tab.  Find the request for script.js.  Look at the response.  Does it look like script.js should?

Don't use VSCode's live server extension.
You need to add code to your server.js to serve up .js files properly (i.e. with

'Content-Type', 'text/javascript'

) when they are asked for.
For example, change your server.js file like this:
const http2 = require('http2');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'server.key')),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'server.cert'))
};
const server = http2.createSecureServer(options, (req, res) => {
  if( req.url == "/"  || req.url == "index.html" )  sendHtml( res, "index.html" )
  else if( req.url.endsWith( ".js" ) ) sendJs( res, req.url )
} )


function sendHtml( res, filename ) {
  const filePath = path.join( __dirname, filename );

  fs.readFile( filePath, (error, data) => {
    if( error ) {
      res.statusCode = 500;
      res.write( `Error reading: ${filePath}` );
      res.end( error.toString() );
    }
    else {
      res.setHeader( 'Content-Type', 'text/html' );
      res.end( data );
    }
  } )
}


function sendJs( res, filename ) {
  const filePath = path.join( __dirname, filename );

  fs.readFile( filePath, (error, data) => {
    if( error ) {
      res.statusCode = 500;
      res.write( `Error reading: ${filePath}` );
      res.end( error.toString() );
    }
    else {
      res.setHeader( 'Content-Type', 'text/javascript' );
      res.end( data );
    }
  } )
}


Thank you very much for answering, but even doing the code that you suggested causes the same Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' error. Leading the script code in the index.html to not function properly
